# How do I make "import * as style from from X.less" work?

Tags: typescript, webpack

I recently ran into this code:

```
import * as style from './style.css';
```

I don't understand the magic involved, but I like it. It's cool. But it would be cooler if I could make this work with .less files. Is this possible?

Using Typescript + React + Webpack.

Comment: you need to do stuff in `typings.d.ts` to make things like this work. Check your `typings.d.ts` it should already have some stuff for `.css` files.

Comment: what does your `webpack.config.js` file look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a [loader](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/#loaders) in order to make Webpack import files other than `.js` files. Loader converts a file to a JS code so that Webpack can import it. As you try to import a `.less` file, you need [less-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/less-loader) (to convert Less to CSS), [css-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader) (to parse the CSS code) and [style-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/style-loader) or [mini-css-extract-plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin) (to make the bundle inject the CSS code to the page).

First install the loaders using NPM (run in a terminal):

```sh
npm install less-loader css-loader style-loader
```

Then tell Webpack that you want to use these loaders for `.less` files: add a rule to your `webpack.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  // ...
  module: {
    rules: [
      // ...
      {
        test: /\.less/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'less-loader'
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

Then tell TypeScript what type your `.less` files are. To do it, find or make a `.d.ts` file (e.g. `src/global.d.ts`) inside you project files and add the following code there:

```
declare module '*.less' {
  const classes: {[key: string]: string};
  export default classes;
}
```

As a result TypeScript will know that the `style` variable from you example is a map of strings. But you need to alter the import code a bit:

```
import style from './style.less';
const cssClass = style.someClass;

// Or just this to inject the CSS code to your bundle
import './style.less';
```

You can find more information in [the official Webpack+Less tutorial](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/less-loader/).